# How to manage Java/Maven Dependencies in JRuby

Tags: maven, rubygems, jruby

I search for the best way to manage java dependancies in a jruby app/library.
Some time ago i read an article about getting java dependancies based on Maven through rubygems. I tried to follow up on this and found some information that this feature was dropped in JRuby 1.7. Also I found some projects like ruby_maven and jbundler but they look like work in progress.

Im especially interested in the integration with bundler and gemspec.
I am no fan of maven and prefer the ruby / bundler way.

Would be nice if a jruby pro could shed some light on the current state.

Comment: If you are a fan of bundler so use it. Furthermore what exactly is your problem ? What have you tried ? What does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me and my coworker are working on a tool to handle mixed Java/JRuby projects. We're hoping to be finished with it this week, so check it out next week and see if it meets your needs. (We still need to update the documentation a little bit, too.)

https://github.com/sam/doubleshot

You had mentioned that JBundler looks like a work in progress, but it does work. I'd recommend giving it a shot if you can't wait a week to try out our project.